# when create docker image using Jenkins, id_rsa.pub key does not pass

Tags: python, docker, jenkins

I'm trying to build docker image file with Jenkins. Jenkins file copy id_rsa and id_rsa.pub to docker file, to pip install bitbucket private repositories. However, I found that id_rsa key is well saved in docker image but id_rsa.pub key file is just empty. I guess because of that docker images shows errors that cannot run pip install bitbucket repos.

This is Jenkins file

```
pipeline {
agent any
environment {
    imageUrl = "$ecsRegistry:$BUILD_NUMBER"
}
stages {
    stage("Docker Build") {
        steps {
            script {
                try {
                    // copy ssh key for install repo lib
                    env.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY = cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa
                    env.SSH_PUBLIC_KEY = cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    echo e
                }
            }
            sh "docker build -t $imageUrl --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="${env.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" --build-arg SSH_PUBLIC_KEY="${env.SSH_PUBLIC_KEY}" ."
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is docker file

```
FROM python:2.7.15-slim-jessie

# arguments
ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
ARG SSH_PUBLIC_KEY

RUN apt-get update -y \
&& apt-get install apt-file -y \
&& apt-file update -y \
&& apt-get install -y python3-dev build-essential libmysqlclient-dev git libffi-dev \
&& pip install --upgrade pip

RUN mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod 0700 ~/.ssh

# Authorize SSH Host
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh && \
chmod 0700 /root/.ssh && \
ssh-keyscan bitbucket.com > /root/.ssh/known_hosts

# Add the keys and set permissions
RUN echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
echo "$SSH_PUBLIC_kEY" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub && \
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

ADD service /app
WORKDIR /app

ADD ./service/requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD ./service/manage.py /app/
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]

EXPOSE 8000
```

This is error log

```
Collecting privaterepo

Cloning ssh://****@bitbucket.org/service/privaterepo.git (to revision v0.5.10) to /tmp/pip-install-apU7vk/privaterepo.git
Running command git clone -q 'ssh://****@bitbucket.org/service/privaterepo.git' /tmp/pip-install-apU7vk/privaterepo.git
key_load_public: invalid format
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q 'ssh://****@bitbucket.org/service/privaterepo.git' /tmp/pip-install-apU7vk/privaterepo.git Check the logs for full command output.


The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

However, If I ssh into docker image and run `pip install ****@bitbucket.org/service/privaterepo.git` it works well. It just fail when docker try to run install private repo when building images.

Comment: This approach leaks your private key into the image, and anyone who gets the image later will be able to retrieve it.  You should do the `git clone` outside the Dockerfile, for example in a `checkout scm` instruction in the Jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your public key is empty because of a typo in variable name: `SSH_PUBLIC_kEY` instead of `SSH_PUBLIC_KEY` (note lowercase `K`). It does not matter though, because public key is not used when authenticating as client, it only uses private key (a public key must be installed on server).

This `Host key verification failed.` indicates problem with your `known_hosts` file, which is probably caused by scanning `bitbucket.com` but cloning from `bitbucket.org`, so it cannot find the matching key for the server.